# matlab - symbolic functions freezing on command window

Tags: matlab

The following code freezes `R2020b` and `R2018b` in the command window with a clean workspace.

```
>> syms f(r, m)
>> f(r, m) = r^(m) * (1-r)^(70000000-m)
 
f(r, m) =
 
r^m*(1 - r)^(70000000 - m)
 
>> f(.001, 5000)
```

Am I using the wrong Matlab tool for this?

Comment: Those exponents are quite hard to resolve. You are essentially resolving `0.995^69995000` numerically. Not sure a computer can give you that number without a big effort

Comment: @AnderBiguri I don’t get the problem. Floating point multiplication is 7 cycles. `70e6 x 7 cycles / CPU_clock`. Even if `CPU_clock` is 100MHz, you get 4.9 secs. So why is it freezing?

Comment: It is not doing floating point multiplications. If it were, it would return `Inf` in a few milliseconds at most. It is doing infinite-precision numeric math, attempting to produce extremely long numbers, which take a lot of time to process.

Comment: For floating-point computations, try `f = @(r, m) r^(m) * (1-r)^(70000000-m)`, without any `sims` declarations.

Comment: @CrisLuengo so I should just use normal m-code function?

Comment: No, because you’ll get `Inf`, which I guess is not useful. What do you want to accomplish? Why are you doing these calculations?

Comment: @CrisLuengo flipping coins, prob H=r, 70e6 times.

Comment: I'm sure there's a better way to do that, but I don't know. I'm sure someone will come along and help you with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
clear
f = @(r, m) r^m * (1-r)^(70000000-m);
f(.001, 5000)
```

It can give the answer immediately.

Besides, I hardly use `syms` because it often freeze my computer.

Comment: What is this `@` construct called? I haven't used Matlab in 10 years and this is new.

Comment: @Bob it may help you https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html